# Measuring parasitic capacitance of coil using an LCR meter

Tags: inductor, parasitic-capacitance

Would it possible to use an LCR meter (DE 5000) to measure the parasitic capacitance of an multi-tapped torid inductor?
If this is possible how should i do this, to get the best results?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is DE 5000?

Comment: Hello Ariser,
Its just the LCR meter i am using.

Best regards.

Comment: Then it might be helpful to add a more detailed description (e.g. link to datasheet). In general two-line questions are prone to elicit answers not matching your question or even none at all. Why not give all information you have on the problem and let sort it out by others?

Answer (score 3):

A regular LCR bridge measures the dominant net impedance. That measured impedance will be inductive if the frequency the bridge uses is below the self-resonant frequency (SRF) of the coil. But, the closer the bridge's test frequency is to SRF, the bigger the error because the parasitic capacitance is starting to become dominant.

If the bridge uses a frequency above the self resonant frequency of the coil then it will indicate a value of capacitance that is somewhat representative of the parasitic capacitance. The higher the frequency is above SRF the better the reading is at representing the true parasitic capacitance.

If your bridge can use multiple frequency settings for measuring impedances then make use of this and, using the standard resonant frequency formula you can estimate the parasitic capacitance.

Comment: Hello Dave, and Andy
Thanks for your replys!
So if i understand this right (excuse me if i totally misunderstood) but should i measure the resistance from COM to each tap with a 100K Hz test frequency this is
the highest test frequency on the meter, and then calculate the capacitance from there?
Sorry i am pretty new to this this so maybe i am totally off here.
This is the circuit the tapped inductor will be used in 
https://i.imgur.com/bMlcqlp.png  

Best regards.

Comment: I would use two test frequencies and make sure they both deliver a value of inductance. The inductance values will not be the same because the effect of parasitic capacitance will affect the reading taken at the higher frequency measurement more but, armed with the two (different) values of inductance, you can derive capacitance mathematically or iteratively using a spreadsheet.

Comment: Okay thank you, i think i understand now, so i would measure L at lowest test frequency possible lets say the reading i get is 29.9mH, then i measure L at highest test frequency possible. 
(i dont know yet if L normally would be higher, or lower with a higher test frequency)
But lets just say i get 40.9mH the difference is +11mH  the 11mH would mostly be capacitive reactance?
Or the alternative method, using a variable frequency source to find the actual
self-resonant frequency, what i understand is that when i have this value, its pretty easy to find C.

Best regards!

Comment: Inductance has to be lower at the higher frequency because capacitive reactance is eating in to its value more at the higher frequency. If you measured dead on the SRF you would get 0 uH of inductance.

Answer (score 1):

Parasitic capacitance is effectively in parallel with the inductance. Together, they form a parallel-resonant circuit, and the frequency at which they resonate is called the "self-resonant frequency" of the inductor.

If you measure the impedance using a test frequency that's well below this self-resonant frequency, you'll be measuring mostly the inductive reactance. If you measure the impedance a a frequency much higher than self-resonance, you'll be measuring mostly the capacitive reactance.

You can't always get an LCR meter (or bridge) to work well at very high frequencies, so an alternative method is to measure the inductance at low frequency, then use a variable-frequency source to find the actual self-resonant frequency of the inductor. Then you can infer the capacitance using the relation

$$f_{SR} = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{LC}}$$

Solving for C gives

$$C = \frac{1}{L (2\pi f_{SR})^2}$$